# "basic.def.odr" paragraph (2.3)

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[[basic.def.odr]/(2.3)](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#2.3):

> If e is a class member access expression, the set contains the
>   potential results of the object expression.

Why does the set of potential results of a class member access contain the potential results of the object expression, instead of the potential results of the *id-expression* denoting the member being accessed?

Comment: E.g. for `a[0].mem`, the potential result is the potential result of `a[0]`, i.e. `a`.

Comment: [Potential results are used to determine whether a variable is odr-used](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#4). Class members are not variables.

Comment: @xskxzr I agree, but static data members can be considered variables (see [this](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-discussion/q6lmY41Rgoo/CmoR6ILXCwAJ)). Thus, it seems to me, the potential results of an object expression should include the *id-expression* of a static data member of a class. I'd like to hear your opinion on this.

Comment: I don't know. Now I'm not even sure whether non-static class members are variables.

Comment: @xskxzr Well, it makes a lot of sense to me the fact that non-static class members are not variables. Thanks anyway..

Comment: https://wg21.link/CWG2353